# Is it possible convert text to regex?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

As example i have this text

1. `1.2345`
2. `12.345`

So my input form must following the format above. Is it possible to populate regex dynamically. as example we will use format number 1

User input `12.345` so it will return `false`, but when user input `5.5555` it will return `true`, but when user input `1.23` it will return `true` and the number will become `1.2300`

In javascript, i'm doing this

```
var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if (inputVal == "") return;
        if (inputVal.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var inputValSplitdot = inputVal.split(".");
            var inputFormatSplitDot = inputFormat.split(".");
            if (inputValSplitdot[1].length < inputFormatSplitDot[1].length) {
                var compareResult = inputFormatSplitDot[1].length - inputValSplitdot[1].length
                var zeroItem = "0".repeat(compareResult);
                $(this).val(inputVal + zeroItem);
            }
        } else {
            $(this).val(inputVal + ".").change();
        }
```

How can i achive in flutter/dart ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved elegantly in Flutter.

[image: demo gif]

First, use RegEx in `InputFormatter` to make sure users can only enter digits (0-9) and decimal points (.) but not any other characters

```
inputFormatters: [
  // Make sure user can only enter numbers and decimal points
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9\.]')),
],
```

Secondly, limit the total input length to 6, so users cannot enter more than that:

```
maxLength: 6
```

*(Once this is done, Flutter automatically adds a counter, if you don't want the counter, it can be disabled easily by setting `counterText: ''`.)*

Lastly, monitor the input with a `TextEditingController`, and check if the value entered is valid and within range:

```
bool isValid(String input) {
  if (input.isEmpty) return true; // initial empty string is okay
  final number = double.tryParse(input); // try to parse the string
  if (number == null) return false; // parse failed: invalid format
  if (number >= 100) return false; // range failed: larger than 99.999
  return true;
}
```

Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("TextField Demo")),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: VerifiedTextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerifiedTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifiedTextFieldState createState() => _VerifiedTextFieldState();
}

class _VerifiedTextFieldState extends State<VerifiedTextField> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _valid = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final valid = isValid(_controller.text);
      setState(() => _valid = valid);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      inputFormatters: [
        // Make sure user can only enter numbers and decimal points
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9\.]')),
      ],
      maxLength: 6,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorText: _valid ? null : "Incorrect Format",
        // counterText: '', // apply this code, if you don't want a counter
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isValid(String input) {
    if (input.isEmpty) return true; // initial empty string is okay
    final number = double.tryParse(input); // try to parse the string
    if (number == null) return false; // parse failed: invalid format
    if (number >= 100) return false; // range failed: larger than 99.999
    return true;
  }
}
```

And of course, if you prefer to do it the way you had in JS, you can modify the `isValid` function accordingly.

Comment: According to the user's requests, I think you should integrate the regex with a quantifier in order to limit the digits before the decimal point. Limiting the maximum length to 6 is not enough.

Comment: @MarcoSacchi There's no need to use RegEx for that, the range check already covers that case and the code is a lot easier to read. Once users enter more than 2 digits before the decimal, it will fail at "number >= 100".

Comment: I was referring to this sentence in the question "User input 12.345 so it will return false", so for _format number 1_ the user expects a single digit before the decimal point. You could specify the two checks necessary to use the two required formats: number >= 100 (as you wrote), and number >= 10.

Comment: @MarcoSacchi Ahhh, I just read the question again, and you are absolutely correct. It seems the OP was asking for 2 different (and competing) situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with string then this might be helpful.

There are two ways to construct a regular expression in JavaScript .

1. Using a regular expression literal, which consists of a pattern enclosed between slashes, as follows.
   const reg = /ab+/;
2. Calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows.
   const reg = new RegExp('ab+', flag);

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

First, check if the number provided accomplished the regex expression

```
bool isMatch(String value) {
        var hasMatch = !RegExp("^\d\.\d+").hasMatch(value);
    
        if (hasMatch && value.length < 6) newText(value);
    
        return hasMatch;
      }
```

Secondly, modify the number length if necessary

```
void newText(String value) {
        for (var i = value.length; i < 6; i++) {
          value += '0';
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in javascript

```
// returns true if pattern matches text
function checkPattern(pattern, input) {
    return (input.match(pattern)) ? true : false
}

// regex pattern
let pattern = /[0-9]{1}[.][0-9]{4}/g
let pattern2 = /[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}/g

let input = ["1.2345", "12.345", "5.5555", "1.23"]

for (let i in input) {
    console.log(`checking first pattern on input: ${input[i]}  ${checkPattern(pattern, input[i])}`)
    console.log(`checking second pattern on input: ${input[i]}  ${checkPattern(pattern2, input[i])}`)
}
```

the output is

```
checking first pattern on input: 1.2345  true
checking second pattern on input: 1.2345  false
checking first pattern on input: 12.345  false
checking second pattern on input: 12.345  true
checking first pattern on input: 5.5555  true
checking second pattern on input: 5.5555  false
checking first pattern on input: 1.23  false
checking second pattern on input: 1.23  false
```